# how to format date display by record source in dreamweaver

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following piece for code from my project in MySQL and php. Its a table row that displays a date. The date field is called [DatePosted] as per below. When I run the code, the date is displayed in 2016-07-11 09:53:15 format which I don't want. I want it to be displayed in 11-07-2016 09:53:15 format.

Can you help me to achieve this please, and where in the code below can I insert the formatting script?

Comment: Show what you got...

Comment: You missed the code

Comment: echo date('d-m-Y H:s:i',strtotime($date_variable));

Comment: sry echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s',strtotime($date_variable));

Comment: I have this.   <tr> <td><?php echo $row_rsResDetails['CheckInDate']; ?></td>. Where can i insert the echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s",strtotime($YOUR_DATE_VARIABLE));

Answer (score 0):

You can use [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) functions of **PHP** to get the formatted date from given string.

Here is how you can do it,

```
echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s",strtotime($YOUR_DATE_VARIABLE));
```

> In above code **strtotime** function converts any English textual datetime
>   description into a Unix timestamp and,
>  **date** function accepts two parameters, first is the date format you want to get and second parameter accepts unix timestamp.
> Second parameter in **date** function is optional, if not given it displays the current date in given format.

**Demo:** https://eval.in/603859

Comment: Thank Alok and team, I solved this in the following way. 

<tr>
          <td ><?php echo date("d-m-y",strtotime($row_rsResDetails['CheckInDate'])); ?></td>

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in the following way.

```
<tr>
  <td><?php echo date("d-m-y",strtotime($row_rsResDetails['CheckInDate'])); ?>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: <tr>
      <td ><?php echo date("d-m-y",strtotime($row_rsResDetails['CheckInDate'])); ?></td>